# DAO pattern with realm

Tags: java, android, realm

How can DAO be used with realm? Because when in my activity I try to set members of my model class I get an exception :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction.

I know that using `realm.executeTransaction` fixes the issue, but the code in my activity is no more database-agnostic because it will countain code that is specific to low level database communication. So later if I want to change database, the refactoring will cost a lot of time and work... Besides, I will have to handle in all my activities a reference to `Realm.getDefaultInstance();`

Here is sample of code of my activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mBook = mBookDaoImpl.getBookById(bookId);
}

// Later in the code

private void saveBook(String name)
{
    mBook.setName(name);
}
```

Here is my model class

```
public class Book extends RealmObject
{
    @Required
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private String name;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getter setter methods
}
```

Here is my DAO interface :

```
public interface BookDao
{
    List<Book> getAllBooks();

    Book getBookByIsbn(int isbn);

    void saveBook(Book book);

    void deleteBook(Book book);
}
```

And finally is my implementation :

```
public class BookDaoImpl implements BookDao
{
    private static BookDaoImpl INSTANCE = null;

    private Realm mRealm;

    private BookDaoImpl()
    {
        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    public static BookDaoImpl getInstance()
    {
        if (INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = new BookDaoImpl();

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooks()
    {
        return mRealm.where(Book.class).findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Book getBookById(String id)
    {
        return mRealm.where(Book.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveBook(final Book book)
    {
        mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction()
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm)
            {
                if (book.getId() == null)
                    book.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(book);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteBook(final Book book)
    {
        mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction()
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm)
            {
                mRealm.where(Counter.class).equalTo("id", book.getId())
                        .findFirst()
                        .deleteFromRealm();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm's `getInstance()` method returns a `thread-local, reference counted instance which must be paired with a close() call`, so your DAO implementation probably won't suit what you expect.

If you use my library [Realm-Monarchy](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy) which I created specifically for making it easier to "abstract Realm away", then you can implement your DAO like this:

```
public class BookDaoImpl implements BookDao
{
    private static BookDaoImpl INSTANCE = null;

    private Monarchy monarchy;

    private BookDaoImpl(Monarchy monarchy)
    {
        this.monarchy = monarchy;
    }

    public static BookDaoImpl getInstance(Monarchy monarchy)
    {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(BookDaoImpl.class) {
                if(INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = new BookDaoImpl(monarchy);
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooks()
    {
        return monarchy.fetchAllCopiedSync((realm) -> realm.where(Book.class));
    }

    @Override
    public Book getBookById(final String id)
    {
        List<Book> books = monarchy.fetchAllCopiedSync((realm) -> realm.where(Book.class).equalTo("id", id));
        if(books.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return books.get(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void saveBook(final Book book)
    {
        monarchy.runTransactionSync((realm) -> {
            if (book.getId() == null)
                book.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            realm.insertOrUpdate(book);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteBook(final Book book)
    {
        monarchy.runTransactionSync((realm) -> {
                realm.where(Counter.class).equalTo("id", book.getId())
                        .findFirst()
                        .deleteFromRealm();
        });
    }
}
```

P.S.: you're throwing away a lot of power/functionality if you return `List<T>` synchronously, instead of an observable like `LiveData<List<T>>` (or originally, `RealmResults<T>`).